# My Hyper-V VM disappeared

Tags: hyper-v

I went to access one of my VMs, and it's gone. I pulled up Hyper-V and it's not there (this was the only VM on this system).

There is no .VHDX file anywhere on my system.

I did a search for and file with the VM name in it and only found AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\Fiona.vhd.lnk

How do I get my VM (Fiona) back?

Comment: If you're going to downvote this, please state why. And yes I did a Google search on this issue - nothing I found matches my situation as best as I can tell.

Comment: Nothing just disappears. Look for the person who deleted it. Then restore it from backup.

Comment: @MichaelHampton No one else has access to that computer. And I have not logged in to the root server for months. So I don't think there's any way it was done by a person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a great solution from a Microsoft tech. The VM files were there even though Hyper-V didn't see them. So we first tried importing them. That failed.

But then she had a great idea - create a new VM, but for the hard drive, use the existing vhd file. That worked.

And the key thing on recovery is not the VM itself, that was easy to recreate. It's the actual content ont hat VM and the vhd had all that. So the Windows instance on the vhd booted right up and all was good.

So short answer, if your VM disappears, if you still have the vhd file and it's good, create a new VM and use that vhd.

Default location for the Hyper V files is "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V" for VM config files and "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks" for Virtual disks.